# Open Layer 3 blank fields when dragging map, how to restrict it

Tags: javascript, drag, openlayers-3, pan

I don't want that the users see the blank field when dragging the map. I want restrict it. I didn't find any great resolution.

my map code:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new  ol.source.MapQuest({ layer: 'osm' }) }), vectorLayer],
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.ScaleLine(),
        new ol.control.ZoomSlider()
    ]),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-6217890.205764902, -1910870.6048274133],
        zoom: 3,
        maxZoom: 20
    })
});
```

Problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that you could do:

1. Set a background color or image on your map container like in the [examples](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/simple.html) to make the white gaps look nicer.

   ```
   .map {
     ...
     background: url(map-background.jpg) repeat;
   }
   ```
2. Set the `minZoom` property on the [view](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.View.html) to prevent the map from being zoomed out too far. But on large screens users might still see gaps.

   ```
   view: new ol.View({
       ...
       minZoom: 4
   })
   ```
3. Or restrict the view extent to the tile boundaries (`ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857').getExtent()`). This is not [yet](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/2777) included in OpenLayers, but you'll find a work-around in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28594215/119937).

Comment: Using this way already helped me

var extent = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857').getExtent();
view: new ol.View({
                center: [-6217890.205764902, -1910870.6048274133],
                zoom: 3,
                maxZoom: 20,
                minZooM: 3,
                extent: extent
            })

Thank you