# openlayers 3 extent, keep map on screen?

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm trying to build a custom map but am having two issues.  First is that I have the mouse position displayed over the map, but the coordinates keep going outside of the map (for example, the map is 5167x4115 but it still shows coordinates when the mouse is in the black space around it).

Also, is there any way to keep the map on screen?  It seems I can just keep panning and panning into a sea of blackness.  Can I confine the map itself to the confines of the screen?

Here is my map code so far

```
<script>
function load() {
      var mapWidth = 5167;   //5120
      var mapHeight = 4115;  //4096
      //var h_offset = 4115;
      var url = 'maptiles/';
      //var crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

      var imgCenter = [mapWidth / 2, - mapHeight / 2];

      //projection
      var proj = new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'ZOOMIFY',
        units: 'pixels',
        extent: [0, 0, mapWidth, mapHeight]
      });

      var source = new ol.source.Zoomify({
        url: url,
        size: [mapWidth, mapHeight],
       //crossOrigin: crossOrigin
      });
      //transform the mouseposition to the map coordinates
      ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms('EPSG:4326', proj,
        function(coordinate) {
          return [coordinate[0], -coordinate[1]];
        },
        function(coordinate) {
          return [coordinate[0], -coordinate[1]];
        });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.FullScreen()
        ]),
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: source
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          projection: proj,
          center: imgCenter,
          zoom: 1,
          maxZoom: 5
        })
      });
      var mousePosition = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        //coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(),
        coordinateFormat: function(coordinate) {
                        return ol.coordinate.format(coordinate, '{x}, {y}', 0);},
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        target: document.getElementById('mouseposition'),
        undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
      });

      map.addControl(mousePosition);



}
</script>
```

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118383/openlayers-3-max-extent

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/28594215/4094470